# Flutter BlocProvider "The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'"

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have previously working code for over a year, but have recently been forced to upgrade underlying flutter components and am now getting new errors.   Previous code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Type _typeOf<T>() => T;

abstract class BlocBase {
  void dispose();
}

class BlocProvider<T extends BlocBase> extends StatefulWidget {
  BlocProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final T bloc;

  @override
  _BlocProviderState<T> createState() => _BlocProviderState<T>();

  static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
    final type = _typeOf<_BlocProviderInherited<T>>();
    _BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =
        context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget;
    return provider?.bloc;
  }
}

class _BlocProviderState<T extends BlocBase> extends State<BlocProvider<T>> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new _BlocProviderInherited<T>(
      bloc: widget.bloc,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class _BlocProviderInherited<T> extends InheritedWidget {
  _BlocProviderInherited({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final T bloc;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_BlocProviderInherited oldWidget) => false;
}
```

I am getting several errors here now, initially at these three lines:

```
Key key,
@required this.child,
@required this.bloc,
```

Which all state the same error:

```
The parameter can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
```

I am not really sure what this wants from me.   Does anyone have any idea?

Edit:

Additional code issue for anyone reading this later, as discussed with Mohan below.

```
static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
  final type = _typeOf<_BlocProviderInherited<T>>();
  _BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =
      context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget;
  return provider?.bloc;
}
```

It has an issue with this line:

```
context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget;
```

And suggests I replace it with: "getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType" but then if I do this, it gets upset saying:

```
A value of type 'InheritedWidget?' can't be assigned to a variable of type '_BlocProviderInherited<T>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to '_BlocProviderInherited<T>'.
```

And also has an issue with this line:

```
return provider?.bloc;
```

Suggesting I can make the return type nullable by changing the first line to this:

```
static T? of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
```

So just adding that question mark in there... which it seems happy with but I am not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

After flutter 2.0 (Null safety), You need to either pass non-null values or specify that parameter is nullable,

here in your case, you need to mention key as nullable

```
Key? key, // add '?' here, which tells it can be nullable.
```

Also after 2.0 you dont need to add @ to required
it can be

```
required
```

Comment: Hi Mohan, thank you so much for your reply.  Sorry it has taken me a while to get back to you on this one, I have been away.   Your suggestion worked perfectly, except there is still a slight issue with the code I supplied originally, and I have edited the question above to show where the issue is now.

Comment: If it is not nullable then replace ? with !, ? -> the parameter can be nullable, ! -> If you are sure that the parameter won't null then you can add ! so that we are assuring complier that it won't be null, but if it is null, then it will show a red screen.